# Fullscreen android

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

When i click a button, i have to set my activity fullscreen.
searching in internet i found the code for do this.

```
container.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

But i do something wrong because status bar and navigation bar disappears and my activity ramain with the same height.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HC8oB.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rL4J.png)

This is the video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                               
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"              
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"                              
    android:layout_height="match_parent"                             
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"                                 
    tools:context=".VideoActivity">                                  

    <include layout="@layout/content_video" />                       

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton              
        android:id="@+id/close"                                      
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                          
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                         
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"            
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"                           
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"                            
        android:src="@drawable/phone"                                
        app:elevation="0dp"                                          
        app:backgroundTint="#44FF0000" />                            

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton              
        android:id="@+id/screen"                                     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"                          
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                         
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"            
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"                           
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"                             
        android:src="@drawable/fullscreen"                           
        app:elevation="0dp"                                          
        app:backgroundTint="#44000000"/>                             

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this content_video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".VideoActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/video"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/string_video_id"
        android:id="@+id/conference_id"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@color/button_background"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone help me plase?
Thanks

Comment: Since you are using OR on several conditions here it produces different layouts for different combinations of flags better you check the value of each flag and manually get the properties yourself and enter hexa value in setSystemVisiblity.It workes for me well.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way at doing it but the simplest way I use is,

```
    // Fullscreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I put this in the Activity class.

Comment: i've tried this before and works fine but it doesn't hide the navigation bar

Comment: Try the edited code. That also removes the title bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(5894);

    }
}
```

or

```
requestWindowFeature(1);
getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
//above setContentView(R.layout.xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Check t[his source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html).

Comment: reference of code link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html